# Cancancan Ability to Create and Destroy HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am writing authorization for an application which specification as following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

What I want is to write the ability to only allow a manager to add tags for a post.

```
if user.manager?
  can ???
...
```

Comment: one possiblity can :manage, Post.  Then using screens  only allow user to insert (e.g. don't add delete / edit buttons) etc.

Comment: also consoder switching to CanCanCan (based on CanCan) as CanCan no longer maintained.

Comment: sorry I have edited, I actually user Cancancan :). I hope to have a solution such as `can [:create, :destroy], feeds: :tags`